# CloudFormation Update support for "Refer to Resources in Another Stack"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda

I'm using the example from [Walkthrough: Refer to Resources in Another Stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-cross-stack-ref.html) to refer resources from another stack (which I think is incredibly useful and should be an out-of-the-box feature). However, the example does not seem to work with updates, i.e. if a new output was added to the referenced stack.

Interestingly, the lambda function isn't even called according to logs and metrics, so it does not seem to be a problem that can be fixed in code. I do think though that the code should use a different `PhysicalResourceId` on update as per [Replacing a Custom Resource During an Update](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html#d0e28200).

*Note: this is a cross-post from an [unanswered AWS Forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228649)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that CloudFormation does only update a custom resource if one of its properties changes. Once this happens, the custom resource should signal that it changed. So

replace:

```
response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
```

with

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(JSON.stringify(responseData)).digest('hex');
response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData, hash);
```

this will result in following events during an update:

```
15:08:16 UTC+0200  UPDATE_COMPLETE     Custom::NetworkInfo  NetworkInfo 
15:08:15 UTC+0200  UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  Custom::NetworkInfo  NetworkInfo  Requested update required the provider to create a new physical resource
15:08:08 UTC+0200  UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  Custom::NetworkInfo  NetworkInfo
```

This still requires a property to change though. The best that I came up with was passing a pseudo-random parameter to the custom resource:

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "Random": {
      "Description": "Random value to force stack-outputs update",
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "NetworkInfo": {
      "Type": "Custom::NetworkInfo",
      "Properties": {
        "ServiceToken": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["LookupStackOutputs", "Arn"] },
        "Random": { "Ref": "Random" },
        "StackName": { "Ref": "NetworkStackName" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unknown parameters (i.e. `Random`) are simply ignored by the lambda function.